# How to make an automatic installer in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-installer, iexpress

In Windows 7, I have a list of many `.msi` files that have to be executed in a specific order.

Now, I want to pack them into one `.exe` file or `.msi` file that will automatically process without user interaction.

I searched google, many recommend using iexpress. However that tool just allows me to pack many files and run one file `.exe` at the first time.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: My recommendation on the topic is to [use DotNetInstaller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589746/how-to-merge-setup-exe-setup-msi-and-netframework-prerequisite-in-a-single-ins/7589819#7589819). The documentation is sufficient to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are a lot of variants how to do it. Start from banal batch file with self-extracted archive and end with Chained MSI. You should choose what you best know and which tools you have.
If you familiar with MSI technology, you can use `chained MSI` for this purpose. It will be more convinient for install and uninstall for user then others methods. Information about this you can find here on stackoverflow. 
Also you can use different wrappers and installer tools like NSIS, InnoSetup, etc...

Comment: Thanks all but I have found solution for my problem. I use .bat file to simulate in order files that I want to install

Answer (score 0):

OCSetup when working from command line.  You can add system components to an online Windows image, or install and remove MSI components.  You can also use this feature to pass packages on to Package Manager for automatic installation/removal.

Keep in mind that all system MSI's must be staged before installation.  Also, the paths for packages must be SPECIFIED in the servicing section of an unattended installation answer file.

I would recommend installing Windows OEM Preinstallation Kit.